# SSIS did not execute script task upon deployment in SQL Server Agent

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2014, script-task

I have a SSIS job which the first task is to execute the script task. The script task is to check whether the file exists then proceed executing another task. It works perfectly fine when running in the VS and Integration Services.

However, the script task does not run after deployed in SQL Server Agent and it prompted me for the error on the second task. I'm using proxy to execute the job in SQL Server Agent and executed in 32 bit. The job uses SQL Server 2014, VS 2015 and target server version is SQL Server 2014.

Can someone please give me advice on this? Thanks.

Comment: can you check if the owner of the job has the permission to visit that folder?

Comment: yes, the proxy have the access to the folder @LONG

Comment: what does the error message say? and if the error happened on the 2nd task, it is failing at that one, not the script task?

Comment: the error message said that failure in creating file. 
Yes, the error happened on the 2nd task... but I find that the fault lies on script task as I have a variable flag in the script task, by default it is 0. And it forever executing the 2nd task if the script result is flag as 0. @LONG

Comment: does the proxy have the full access? and is the path a UNC path if it is on the shared drive?

Comment: The problem has been solved.. ended up is due to the proxy dont have the access to the folder. The access got removed suddenly... thanks for the help anyway @LONG